# Can't set Image to ImageView. Bug or something else?

Tags: android

It's quite strange how i can't set image from 'res/drawable' to my ImageView. Here is my code:

xml:

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Img"
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
```

java:

```
ImageView imeg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Img);
 if (imeg != null)
       imeg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check_1);
```

its showing nothing

Comment: **imeg.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_1));** try like this

Comment: And did you checked to see if that line of code is being executed? As far as I can see you have a if statement there..

Comment: sure I checked with Toas, its working

Comment: Can i know the resolution of check_1 image. May be its very high compared to your 12dp image view. If so reduse the size of image with a smaller one and please have a try. It will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `imeg.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_1);`.

You are trying to set background resource, while you need to set image resource.

Comment: i had to set my ImageView bitmap to Null and check if its still null or not. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

```
 ImageView imeg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Img);
 if (imeg != null)  {
   imeg.setImageBitmap(null);
   imeg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check_1);
  }
```

Comment: @Alimov Shohrukh check this one.

Comment: NullPointerException bro

Comment: @AlimovShohrukh are you in fragment?

Comment: @AlimovShohrukh what is this bold view (ImageView) **view**.findViewById(R.id.Img);

Comment: thats the strange part, its not a fragment. Activity

Comment: `ImageView imeg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Img);` chagne to `ImageView imeg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Img);`

Comment: @AlimovShohrukh is your issue fixed?

Comment: add your full onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

it wont show nothing unless u change the condition to

```
if (imeg.equal("null"))
       imeg.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_1);
```

check this out if am right with the logic.
The image view is already null where you are checking the condition that whether the image is not equal to null set the background. Change the logic will work i hope

Comment: this gave me NullPointerException bro

Comment: try if(imeg.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))

Comment: is it important to check the condition in your code why cant you  call it outside the condition??

Comment: ok but how to set equalsIgnoreCase("null") to imageview. it doesnt work for it

Comment: its showing "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo -> java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: post your log here

Answer (score 0):

```
imeg.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_1));
```

try this one

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code  to set image to Image view**

```
imeg.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_1);
```

Comment: this should work but somehow its not showing my image in imageView

Comment: android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"